# I calculate the mid index first and then get nums[mid], but it is wrong, I don't know why?

Tags: java

wrong version:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] sortArray(int[] nums) {
        if(nums == null || nums.length == 0){
            return nums;
        }
        
        helper(nums,0,nums.length-1);
        
        return nums;
    }
    private void helper(int[]nums, int start, int end){
        if (start>=end){
            return;
        }
        
        int left = start;
        int right = end ;
        //int pivot = nums[(start + end)/2];
        int mid = (start + end)/2;
        
        while(left<=right){
            while(left<=right && nums[left]<nums[mid]){
                left++;
            }
            
            while(left<=right && nums[right]>nums[mid]){
                right--;
            }
            
            if(left<= right){
                int temp = nums[right];
                nums[right] = nums[left];
                nums[left] = temp;
                left++;
                right--;
}
```

I calculate mid number first , int mid = (start+end)/2 and put nums[mid] into comparison

right version :

```
class Solution {
    public int[] sortArray(int[] nums) {
        if(nums == null || nums.length == 0){
            return nums;
        }
        
        helper(nums,0,nums.length-1);//length没有括号
        
        return nums;
    }
    private void helper(int[]nums, int start, int end){
        if (start>=end){
            return;
        }
        
        int left = start;
        int right = end ;
        int pivot = nums[(start + end)/2];
        //int mid = (start + end)/2;
        
        while(left<=right){
            while(left<=right && nums[left]<pivot){
                left++;
            }
            
            while(left<=right && nums[right]>pivot){
                right--;
            }
            
            if(left<= right){
                int temp = nums[right];
                nums[right] = nums[left];
                nums[left] = temp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }   
        helper(nums,start,right);
        helper(nums,left,end);
    }
```

the only difference is the way that I choose the midpoint, if I calculate mid-index first and then pass nums[mid] into comparison, it is wrong. but If I get midpoint first and then put it into comparison, it is right .... is there any difference???

Comment: this is the question in leetcode,  912. Sort an Array, the wrong version cannot pass the test case , sooooo weird

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down with an example and simulate it through the code:

Say we have an initial array:

```
{29, 23, 17, 57, 34, 89, 65, 27}
```

So, the `sortArray` is called and it takes our input as `nums`. It is passed through the `helper` with parameters `nums`, `start 0` and `end 7`. Now we have:

```
left = 0, right = 7, mid = 3, pivot = 57
```

Now, `left <= right` So it will continue in the while loop. After executing this block:

```
while(left <= right && nums[left] < pivot){  //alternatively nums[mid]
            left++;
}
```

We will get:

```
left = 3, right = 7, mid = 3, pivot = 57
```

Then next block executes:

```
while(left<=right && nums[right]>pivot){
            right--;
}
```

Now we'll get:

```
left = 3, right = 7, mid = 3, pivot = 57
```

Now the last block starts before the recursion takes place:

```
if(left<= right){
    int temp = nums[right];
    nums[right] = nums[left];
    nums[left] = temp;
    left++;
    right--;
}
```

So we get :

```
nums = {29,23,17,27,34,89,65,57}
left = 4, right = 6, mid = 3, pivot = 57
```

The whole block is inside a while loop under condition `left <= right`. So this whole section executes the exact same way, but here's the interesting thing. After the `first outer while iteration`, you now get `mid = 3`, hence `nums[mid] = 27`, where your pivot remains unchanged, `57`, which continues the business for this `while` block until entering to the recursive calls.

So you see, your array gets sorted through the process of swapping position between indexes and it may swap your `mid` element too, but your `mid` index number remains unchanged. Hence the problem occurs. That is why you get the correct result if you take the element in the mid index earlier and work with that, not the mid index.

Hope that clears everything

Comment: really helpful thanks

Comment: @writingcodehard, it if answers your question then please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the array, so the element at the index `mid` can change (i.e., it does not remain constant, but the pivot should be a constant value). That will cause your algorithm to not work in certain cases.

Comment: I don't think so, because start and end don't change

Comment: @writingcodehard What do you mean? `start` and `end` are not relevant at all. `mid` does not change, but `nums[mid]` changes because you're sorting the array.

Comment: @writingcodehard That's not relevant. I didn't say `mid` changes, but that `nums[mid]` is changing because you're moving the elements in the array while sorting.

Comment: @writingcodehard No problem.

Comment: @writingcodehard If this answers your question, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: @Unmitigated *but the pivot should be a constant value*  If you're saying the pivot should be constant thru out the process, that is simply incorrect.

Comment: @WJS I am referring to the scope of the `helper` method only.

Comment: Ah okay.  That makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're changing the array nums and at the same time getting the numbers of it. Just in case you just want to sort an array just use `Arrays.sort(nums)`. On the other hand, you're assuming the mid position of nums will have the mid value of the array which could be not true.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, you're not making any recursive calls to the helper method. And in general you are making this more difficult that it has to be.  No mid point needs to be calculated (the array is unsorted so the mid point is meaningless from that perspective).  The `pivot` can actually be any value in the array to start and may actually change throughout the process. This is typical of partitioned sorts of this type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] v = { 2, 5, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4 };
    v = sortArray(v);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

The main code

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) {
        return nums;
    }
    
    helper(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    
    return nums;
}
    
private static void helper(int[] nums, int left, int right) {
    if (left >= right) { // time to terminate?
        return;
    }
    int pivot = nums[left];
    int i = left - 1;
    int j = right + 1;
    while (true) {
        while (nums[--j] > pivot);
        
        while (nums[++i] < pivot);

        if (i >= j) { // sort the next partitions
            helper(nums, left, j);
            helper(nums, j + 1, right);
            return;
        }
        // or swap the values
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at my solution.  If you have any questions, I will try to answer them.